# How to fire keyboard events in Javascript using onClick?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have an existing function that gets called when KeyD is pressed.

I want to trigger an KeyD event (without actually pressing keyD on keyboard) as soon as I click on some button.

Is it possible in Javascript?

Comment: Yes, you can trigger the _event_ using [dispatchEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent), but that's not the same as striking D key.

Comment: Are you asking how to call a function when a button is clicked?

Comment: hi @Andy, No, I'm asking if there is any way to trigger an keyD keypress event without actually pressing the keyD on keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, it is possible

```js
button.addEventListener('click', function(){
    let keydown = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {key: 'a', code: 'KeyA', keyCode: 65});
    element.dispatchEvent(keydown); // element is the one you want to trigger the event
});
```

the construction of `KeyboardEvent` please read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/KeyboardEvent

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a [`new KeyboardEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/KeyboardEvent), and provide a `key` for `KeyboardEventInit` dictionary which is the second argument.
Then use [`dispatchEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent) to trigger the event on the element.

```js
let elem = document.querySelector("input");

elem.addEventListener("keypress", (e) => {
  if(e.key === "d"){
    keyDPressed();
  }
});

elem.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    let eve = new KeyboardEvent('keypress',{ key : "d"})
    e.target.dispatchEvent(eve);
});

function keyDPressed(e) {   //function that gets called when key D is pressed
  console.log("d was pressed");
}
```

```html
<input value="Click here" type="button">
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to implement dispatchEvent.

```js
let element = document.querySelector('input');
element.onkeydown = e => alert(e.key);
changeValButton.onclick = () => element.value += "a";
dispatchButton.onclick = () => {
   element.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {'key': 'd'}));
}
```

```html
<input/>
<button id="dispatchButton">Press to dispatch event </button>
<button id="changeValButton">Press to change value </button>
```

Comment: What does this have to do with click event OP is asking about?

Comment: sorry, earlier, I misunderstood the question. Now, as per your questions please check my updated answer.

Answer (score -1):

you can use the onkeypress() function from javascript that will trigger on every keyPress.