# How press key combo onclick

Tags: javascript, html

Is is possible to press two keys with an onclick function?

I am hoping to press 'shift' & '=' at the same time with a button.

I found this code on this post:
[How to fire keyboard events in Javascript using onClick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71050387/how-to-fire-keyboard-events-in-javascript-using-onclick)

```js
let elem = document.querySelector("input");

elem.addEventListener("keypress", (e) => {
  if(e.key === "d"){
    keyDPressed();
  }
});

elem.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    let eve = new KeyboardEvent('keypress',{ key : "d"})
    e.target.dispatchEvent(eve);
});

function keyDPressed(e) {   //function that gets called when key D is pressed
  console.log("d was pressed");
}
```

```html
<input value="Click here" type="button">
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, by add `shiftKey: true` to the `KeyboardEvent` constructor options.

```js
let elem = document.querySelector("input");

elem.addEventListener("keypress", (e) => {
  if (e.key === '=' && e.shiftKey) {
    keyEqualPressed(e)
  }
});

elem.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    let eve = new KeyboardEvent('keypress',{ key : "=", shiftKey: true, })
    e.target.dispatchEvent(eve);
});

function keyEqualPressed(e) {   //function that gets called when key = && shift are pressed
  console.log("Key equal and shift pressed");
}
```

```html
<input value="Click here" type="button">
```

Answer (score 0):

You would set [shiftKey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/shiftKey) or one of the other modifier keys

```js
let elem = document.querySelector("input");

elem.addEventListener("keypress", (e) => {
  if (e.key === "d") {
    keyDPressed(e);
  }
});

elem.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  elem.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent("keypress", {
    key: "d",
    altKey: false,
    shiftKey: true,
    ctrlKey: false,
    metaKey: false,
  }));
});

function keyDPressed(e) { //function that gets called when key D is pressed
  console.log("d was pressed", e.shiftKey);
}
```

```html
<input value="Click here" type="button">
```

Comment: The "modifier keys" default to false, would you bother setting them?

Comment: Just showing what they were.